# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions, sqflite

I am using flutter in vs code. I have got this error when I am connecting to sqflite database.
I have added sqflite,path plugin in pubspec.yaml file. I have tried
 `flutter clean`
`flutter run` command too but nothing worked.
This is my Database helper method

```
  final databaseName = "notes.db";
  final tableName = "notes";
  DatabaseHelper._();
  static final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper._();
  static Database _database;

  final fieldMap = {
    "id": "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
    "title": "TEXT",
    "body": "TEXT",
    "creation_date": "DATE",
  };
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;

    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    var path = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = join(path, 'notes.db');
    // ignore: argument_type_not_assignable
    Database dbConnection = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      print("executing create query from onCreate callback");
      await db.execute(_buildCreateQuery());
    });

    await dbConnection.execute(_buildCreateQuery());

    _buildCreateQuery();

    return dbConnection;
  }
```

The values are not getting stored in sqflite databse. It returns null. So what should I do?

Comment: just stop and build the app again to get changes updated in platform specific code after adding new dependencies.........try this might help

Comment: It didn't work. Getting the same error again.

Comment: Try deleting pubspec.lock and run again.